# Android browser: last letter in button is cut off

Tags: android, html, browser, letter

There is a weird bug with Android browser. It cuts off last letters in some places and I have no idea why. The last letter then appears at the left side of the screen at the same height where it supposed to be. Have anyone solved this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahiyY.png

Comment: there is not enough space for the last character.

Comment: @user1113690, please post some code (and/or page URL). The phenomenon looks odd (it took me some time to realize what the issue was: in the button with text “Найти больше отеле”, the last word should have a “й” appended to the last word, but it appears on the very left, as white on light gray). There are probably some CSS settings for the button that may affect this. The HTML markup for the button is relevant, too.

Answer (score 2):

The issue caused by usage of text-shadow. If you remove text-shadow from text everything is fine